# In the alert view ,how to change background color & display bottom of view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertview

I want to change the `UIAlertView` view background colour and change displaying position of alert view.

Is it posible ?

Comment: The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Comment: then how will change the BG ?

Comment: Create custom View that fits your requirement

Comment: You have to go for custom alert view. Check some custom from below link:  https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/uialertview

Comment: check link provided by Fawad , Use that one

Comment: can anyone pink me,simple alert view with textfield in the viewDidLoad method that must be change the background Colour of alert view.

Answer (score 2):

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

For more information about appearance and behaviour configuration, see [AlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView).

**OR**

for changing background color u me used

- [WCAlertView](https://github.com/m1entus/WCAlertView)
- [SCLAlertView](https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView)

**OR**
 u can refer this post [iOS SDK: Creating a Custom Alert View](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-creating-a-custom-alert-view--mobile-16842)

Comment: can anyone pink me,simple alert view with textfield in the viewDidLoad method that must be change the background Colour of alert view.

Comment: but i wanna  simple code that code could be hard to understand thats why i post again could u help?

Comment: first of all there is no direct way to doing all this task in alertview. if it is necessary to do you need to use  any available third party app or should design your custom alertview

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. You can make custom AlertView for that. Take a look at this https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview.

Comment: can anyone pink me,simple alert view with textfield in the viewDidLoad method that must be change the background Colour of alert view.