# How can I display an UIAlertView as full screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertview

How can I display an UIAlertView as full screen in iOS ?
Am very problem some times pop up tableview. So using alertview displaying tableview is easy but it is not expandng size. For that how can dispaly alertview in full screen in iOs ?

Comment: you can't change alert view size so better way you create custom view and use as alert view.

Comment: If I understand you correctly this isn't possible the view hierarchy of a `UIAlertView` can't be altered and you would need to alter the view to get what you are after, the reason it can't be alter is because it is part of a private class check out the section marked **Subclassing Notes** in the apple docs here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html. So I'd advise to google custom alert views.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659049/in-the-alert-view-how-to-change-background-color-display-bottom-of-view/30659132#30659132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change/alter apples default [UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html).

Instead use custom view and mimic and behavior of it, and you might want to add `YourCustomAlertView` to like:

> CustomAlert.h

```
@interface CustomAlert : NSObject

+ (void)alertShow;

+ (void)alertHide;

@end
```

> CustomAlert.m

```
@implementation CustomAlert

+ (void)alertShow 
{
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    UIView *existingView = [window viewWithTag:123456789];

    if (existingView != nil ) // removes existing alert view to avoid multi occurance
    {
        [existingView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    UIView *YourCustomAlertView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:YourFrame];

    YourCustomAlertView.tag = 123456789; // add tag to remove the view later

    // ...

    [window addSubview: YourCustomAlertView]; 
    //this will place your `YourCustomAlertView` to the top most like the default UIAlertView... 

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{ [YourCustomAlertView setAlpha:1]; }];
}

+ (void)alertHide
{
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    UIView * YourCustomAlertView = [window viewWithTag: 123456789];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

        [YourCustomAlertView setAlpha:0];

    } completion:^(BOOL done){ if (done) { [YourCustomAlertView removeFromSuperview]; } }];
}

@end
```

Using it like:

`[CustomAlert alertShow];`

**Note:** This is just a guide to make `CustomUIAlertView` or if you dont feel like making your own search for some ready made `CustomAlertView`, sorry i dont use any so i can't recommend..

This is just an example you can change anything at will, perhaps you like to add `initWithTitle: message: button:` its up to you. and many other details...

Cheers! :)

Comment: I didn't understand can you give me any link of example code.

Answer (score 0):

[iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802-CH3-SW8) says:

> Use the properties and methods defined in this class to set the title, message, and delegate of an alert view and configure the buttons. You must set a delegate if you add custom buttons. The delegate should conform to the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol. Use the show method to display an alert view once it is configured.

so there is no way to modify the `UIALertView`. You need to create your own `AlertView`.

Just create a view and make it visible when you need show an alert. Also there are examples on [github like this](https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView) . Also you can find on [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/?q=customalert) examples.